# Android Register application as context in LiveData

Tags: android, observable, android-livedata

I am trying to register the application to the observer but I get this message:

> requires: 'android.arch.lifecycle.LifecycleOwner

Any ideas?

```
public class CompanyMV extends AndroidViewModel{

public CompanyMV(Application application) {

    super(application);
    repo.getNumbers(this.ID).observe(application, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer number) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`observe()` is for use by activities, fragments, and other things with a discrete lifecycle. An `Application` does not have that — it lives as long as your process does.

Use `observeForever()` instead of `observe()` here.

Comment: Do we have to call remove observer when closing the app to avoid memory leaks ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy: I do not know what you mean by "closing the app" in this context. The question is about a `ViewModel`. You would want to call `removeObserver()` in `onCleared()` of the `ViewModel` to not leak the observer.

Comment: If i'm using observeForever() in Application class onCreate(), then where should i call removeObserver() ?

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy: Nowhere. An `Application` is never destroyed until the entire process is terminated.